# How to create an android service that runs after the activity has ended

Tags: android, service

I have a android app that has an ongoing service for tracking a persons location. I want to be able to start up the service from within the activity and end it from within the activity. When the activity is running I need to be able to bind to the service and communicate to it via aidl. However I need the service to continue even when the activity has ended. I only want the service to end when the it is told to by the activity.

So far I have my activity and service and they can communicate through a aidl file. But at the moment the service ends when the activity does.

How do I get it to continue running when the activity has ended AND how do I rebind to it when the activity is restarted?

Comment: Can you show some snippets? I have created an activity that starts a service but when the activity finishes, the service remains running.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then after a couple of days (whatever the minimum is) select it as the answer.

Comment: any chance in sharing your code for this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out.

I was using the `bindService` method which created my service for me and bound to it (I need a binding), but if a service is created via a call to `bindService` the service only lives as long as the binding and so when calling `unbindService`, which I was doing when my activity was destroyed, the service itself also was destroyed.

However if you create your service with a call to `createService` and then call `bindService` you will bind to the already running service. Then when you come to unbind from it, it no longer destroys itself. The service will continue until you call `stopService`.

Then when you re-enter your activity you can check if the service is already running and if it is just call `bindService` other wise just call `startService` followed by `bindService`

Comment: Very basic tutorial but teacher explains it perfectly on how to create a service http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfWsp9IHX1Y

Comment: Beautiful video. I learnt much more from it than just the Service. Thank you